# Getting current UIViewController in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I'm loading an application (via embedded framework) via a PhoneGap Plugin.
Now, I'm trying to pass the current UIViewController to the **parentViewController** property of the *FlashizFacade* object. 

When I execute my application I'm getting this error in the debug console when assigning *self*:

> > 2012-09-10 13:01:43.663 gTicketSales[2805:16a03] -[FlashizPlugin navigationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91925e0
> >
> > 2012-09-10 13:01:43.665 gTicketSales[2805:16a03] ***WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:`<NSInvalidArgumentException>`-[FlashizPlugin navigationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91925e0

When assigning *self.viewController*:

> > > 2012-09-10 14:31:21.455 gTicketSales[3693:16a03] ***WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:`<Wrong parentViewController specified>`When using non-modal display, parentViewController have to be an instance of UIViewController with a valid navigationController assigned

I've tried:

```
facade.parentViewController = self;
facade.parentViewController = self.viewController;
```

#### My .h file

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <FlashizPaymentLib/FlashizFacade.h>

@interface FlashizPlugin : CDVPlugin <FlashizPaymentDelegate> {}

@property (nonatomic, retain) FlashizFacade* flashizFacade;
- (void) openFlashiz:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

#### My .m file

```
#import "FlashizPlugin.h"
@implementation FlashizPlugin
@synthesize flashizFacade;

- (void) openFlashiz:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options     {


NSLog(@"Flashiz Payment Opening...");

NSString *callbackId = [arguments pop];
NSString *invoiceId = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];

FlashizFacade* facade = [[FlashizFacade alloc] initWithEnvironment:FE_TEST];
facade.parentViewController = self;
facade.delegate = self;
self.flashizFacade = facade;
[facade executePaymentForInvoiceId:invoiceId];
[facade release];

CDVPluginResult *result;

result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"Flashiz Payment Executed..."];
[self writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];

}


@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

on AppDelegate.m change this line on `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

for this

```
    UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]                                                  initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.navigationController = aNavigationController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

In my project is crashing because I don't have a `ConnectionViewController`, I think I didn't include the framework correctly, because I didn't know whato to do with the Resources folder, but I think it should work for you.

EDIT: I just included the resources folder, and it's working!!!

And if you don't want the navigationBar on the phonegap's view controller put in the `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController.m`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't work either.
The problem is that I can't access the facade object because it is a framework we have to implement.

Comment: Then try to add a navigationController to phonegap's MainViewController. If you tell me where can I download the Flashiz SDK I can try to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will upload the SDK when I'm at my pc.

Comment: Here you can download the SDK: [FlashizSDK](http://users.telenet.be/haxyGen/FlashizPaymentLib.embeddedframework.zip)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I will try this afternoon

Comment: I've been trying to fix it all day again. Still no result. I succeeded in removing the errors by creating a new UINavigationController and a new UIViewController. But now I can't get it presented (at least I think because the FlashIZ ViewController doesn't show up.)